# Nextjs redirecting and updating changes not working in strapi apollo graphql authentication

Tags: reactjs, next.js, graphql, apollo, strapi

I am implementing authentication on nextjs strapi graphql and I want to redirect user once he registers or logins or theres is jwt token in cookies but when I login. its not redirecting using router.push method, I am also checking in other pages if user exist in cookies but use`Effect not working Here is my code example
System Information
4.1.11:
Macos:
Mysql:
14.17.00:
6.14.13:
1.22.19:

```
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Image from "next/image";
import Link from "next/link";
import { useMutation } from "@apollo/client";
import { LOGIN_USER } from "../../gql/mutations";
import { userContext } from "../../context/wrapppers/UserWrapper";
import { setUserAction } from "../../context/actions/user-actions";
import { SIGN_IN } from "../../context/actions/action-types";

import { useRouter } from "next/router";

function login() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { user, dispatchUser } = useContext(userContext);
  const [credentials, setCredentials] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    if (user !== "" && user !== undefined) {
      router.push("/account");
    }
  }, []);

  const [loginUser, { loading, error, data }] = useMutation(LOGIN_USER);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
      dispatchUser(
        setUserAction(
          {
            token: data.login.jwt,
            username: data.login.user.username,
            id: data.login.user.id,
            email: data.login.user.email,
          },
          SIGN_IN
        )
      );
    }
  }, [data]);

  if (loading) return <h1>logging in...</h1>;
  if (error) return <h1>{error.message}</h1>;

  console.log("user from login page", user);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setCredentials({
      ...credentials,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
  };

  const handleLogin = (e) => {
    if (typeof window === "undefined") {
      return;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    loginUser({
      variables: {
        input: credentials,
      },
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="h-screen bg-slate-50 flex justify-center items-center w-full">
      {error && <div>{error.message}</div>}
      <form onSubmit={handleLogin}>
        <div className="bg-white px-10 py-8 rounded-xl w-screen shadow-md max-w-sm">
          <Image
            src={require("../../public/Img/logo.png")}
            height={50}
            objectFit="contain"
            className="h-14 mb-4 mx-auto"
            alt=""
          />
          <div className="space-y-4">
            <h1 className="text-center text-2xl font-semibold text-gray-600">
              Login
            </h1>
            <div>
              <label
                for="email"
                className="block mb-1 text-gray-600 font-semibold"
              >
                Email or Username
              </label>
              <input
                name="identifier"
                onChange={handleChange}
                type="text"
                required
                className="bg-indigo-50 px-4 py-2 outline-none rounded-md w-full"
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <label
                for="password"
                className="block mb-1 text-gray-600 font-semibold"
              >
                Password
              </label>
              <input
                name="password"
                onChange={handleChange}
                type="text"
                required
                className="bg-indigo-50 px-4 py-2 outline-none rounded-md w-full"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <button
            type="submit"
            className="mt-4 w-full bg-yellow-500 font-semibold py-2 rounded-md  tracking-wide"
          >
            Login
          </button>
          <Link href="account/register">
            <h3 className="mt-2 cursor-pointer">Or Create an account</h3>
          </Link>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default login;

function index() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { user, dispatchUser } = useContext(userContext);

  const [getUserOrders, { loading, error, data }] = useLazyQuery(USER_ORDERS);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      getUserOrders({
        variables: {
          filters: {
            user: {
              id: {
                eq: user.id,
              },
            },
            status: {
              ne: "rejected",
            },
          },
        },
      });
    } else {
      router.push("/account/login");
    }
  }, [user]);

  if (error) return <div>{error.message}</div>;
  if (loading) return <div>Loading ...</div>;

  const handleLogout = () => {
    router.push("/account/login");
    dispatchUser(setUserAction(user, SIGN_OUT));
  };


    return (
      <div>
        <section className="py-5 sm:py-7 bg-gray-100">
          <div className="container max-w-screen-xl mx-auto px-4">
            Home/Account
          </div>
        </section>

        <section className="py-10">
          <div className="container max-w-screen-xl mx-auto px-4">
            <div className="flex flex-col md:flex-row -mx-4">
              <aside className="md:w-1/3 lg:w-1/4 px-4">
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <Link href="/account">
                      <span className="block px-3 py-2 text-primary bg-gray-100 hover:bg-orange-100  rounded-md">
                        Account
                      </span>
                    </Link>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <div
                      className="cursor-pointer flex items-center"
                      onClick={handleLogout}
                    >
                      <IoIosLogOut size="20" className="mr-2" />
                      <span>Log out</span>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </aside>
              <main className="md:w-2/3 lg:w-3/4 px-4">
                <article className="border border-gray-200 bg-white shadow-sm rounded mb-5 p-3 lg:p-5">
                  <figure className="flex items-start sm:items-center">
                    <AiOutlineUser size="50" />
                    <figcaption>
                      <h5 className="font-semibold text-lg">
                        Hi {user.username}
                      </h5>
                      <p>Email: {user.email}</p>
                    </figcaption>
                  </figure>

                  <hr className="my-4" />

                  <h3 className="text-xl font-semibold mb-5">Order History</h3>

                  {data && data.orders.data.length !== 0 ? (
                    data.orders.data.map(({ id, attributes }, orderIndex) => (
                      <article
                        key={id}
                        className="p-3 lg:p-5 mb-5 bg-white border border-blue-600 rounded-md"
                      >
                        <header className="lg:flex justify-between mb-4">
                          <div className="mb-4 lg:mb-0">
                            <p className="font-semibold">
                              <span>Order ID: #{id} </span>
                              <span className="text-green-500">
                                {" "}
                                • {attributes.status}{" "}
                              </span>
                            </p>
                            <p className="text-gray-500">
                              {" "}
                              {new Date(
                                attributes.createdAt
                              ).toLocaleDateString()}
                            </p>
                          </div>
                        </header>

                        <hr className="my-4" />

                        <div className="grid md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 gap-2">
                          {attributes.products.data.map(
                            ({ id, attributes }, productIndex) => (
                              <Link href={`/shop/${attributes.slug}`}>
                                <figure
                                  key={id}
                                  className="flex flex-row mb-4 cursor-pointer"
                                >
                                  <div>
                                    <Image
                                      src={`${
                                        BACKEND_URL +
                                        attributes.media.data[0].attributes.url
                                      }`}
                                      width={80}
                                      height={80}
                                      objectFit="cover"
                                      className="rounded"
                                    />
                                  </div>
                                  <figcaption className="ml-3">
                                    <p className="text-gray-600">
                                      {attributes.name}
                                    </p>
                                    <p className="mt-1 font-semibold">
                                      {
                                        data.orders.data[orderIndex].attributes
                                          .details[productIndex].quantity
                                      }{" "}
                                      x ${attributes.price}
                                    </p>
                                  </figcaption>
                                </figure>
                              </Link>
                            )
                          )}
                        </div>
                      </article>
                    ))
                  ) : (
                    <EmptyState
                      title="You have not yet ordered"
                      subtitle="Choose some products to order"
                      image={EmptyOrder}
                      btnText="Go to shop"
                      btnText2="Go Home"
                      btnLink="/shop"
                      btnLink2="/"
                    />
                  )}
                </article>
              </main>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    );

}

export default index;
```

I am quite new in nextjs and graphql any suggesstion highly appreciated!

Comment: it did not work